# MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT E.snum 
FROM Enrolled E 
GROUP BY E.snum 
HAVING COUNT (*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM enrolled E2 
                         GROUP BY E2.snum)
```

But it generates an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enrolled E2 GROUP BY E2.snum)
>   LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

**What does the error mean?  Why it doesn't allow me to use ALL operator?**

Comment: Can you also post some sample data with expected result set so that we can better understand what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to Find the names of students enrolled in the maximum number of classes.Consider the following relations: Student(snum: integer, sname: string, major: string, level: string, age: integer)
Class(name: string, meets at: string, room: string, fid: integer)
Enrolled(snum: integer, cname: string)
Faculty(fid: integer, fname: string, deptid: integer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT E.snum, COUNT(E.snum) 
FROM Enrolled E 
GROUP BY E.snum 
HAVING COUNT (E.snum) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM enrolled E2 
                         GROUP BY E2.snum)
```

Comment: Your suggestion works. But Why count(*) doesn't work? Just for knowledge. I am a learner.

Comment: @HeliShah Mark answer, if it helps